# is a separate NSManagedObjectContext required to roll back coredata changes the user does not OK?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is a separate NSManagedObjectContext required to roll back coredata changes the user does not OK?

I note in the [CoreDataBooks example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405) it uses a separate NSManagedObjectContext.  What would like to ask is whether this is the only real way to handle the requirement, and if no, what would be the altermative approach.

Requirement being:

- allow user to start making changes to fields in an object on a page
- this may include passing off to separate modal views to help them set this data
- offer a OK or CANCEL re going ahead with the changes or not
- as part of making the changes you still keep using your CoreData managed objects (i.e. no creation of a separate set of objects/approach to handle this)
- so like, given you want to stick to using the existing core data objects, then to have support for OK and CANCEL changes, is the only way to do this by having a separate 2nd NSManagedObjectContext?

EXTRACT FROM EXAMPLE FOR REFERENCE

> Creates a new book, an AddViewController to manage addition of the
>   book, and a new managed object context for the add controller to keep
>   changes made to the book discrete from the application's managed
>   object context until the book is saved.  IMPORTANT: It's not necessary
>   to use a second context for this. You could just use the existing
>   context, which would simplify some of the code -- you wouldn't need to
>   merge changes after a save, for example. This implementation, though,
>   illustrates a pattern that may sometimes be useful (where you want to
>   maintain a separate set of edits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a separate `NSManagedObjectContext` is by far the easiest way to handle the case you describe. It is also the only way to do it if you want to make changes on a separate thread.

Just be sure to use `-[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification]` during saving to keep your main `NSManagedObjectContext` properly in sync.